# Can I restrict access to a Google site to some Google Cloud Identity users?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-sites, google-workspace

Maybe my question is basic. I have a domain on Google Cloud Identity Free Edition. I created a Google Site with a super admin account (with license G Suite), however I need to share that site to another users with license Cloud Identity. I shared the site, but they can't see it. I need to add some configuration? Or is not possible to access a Google Site (only view) without G Suite License?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud Identity users can't access any G Suite services including free services availbale thru Gmail account.

Comment: May you give me link for more details, please?

Comment: I know Google Cloud Identity Free can't access Google Site as a part of G Suite, but i can't find more detail from Google as a proof.

Comment: @TrầnHữuHiền https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/7319251?hl=en#:~:text=Cloud%20Identity%20Free%20edition%20includes,Slides%2C%20Keep%2C%20and%20Meet.